# Creating clipping mask with an outlined stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke

I've created this logo which uses clipping masks to contain the field inside the outline of the state. As you can see, the state outline is still a path. I need to convert this to an outlined stroke so that it can be resized without affecting the stroke weight.

[image]

However, when I use the direct selection tool (A) to select the state outline and convert it to outlines, this is what happens with the clipping mask:

[image]

I have also tried removing all clipping masks from the start, converting the path to outlines, and then applying the clipping mask but this is the result of those steps:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to get the state outline stroke outlined and still have the field graphics contained within?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: What is the inner graphic? Paths? Strokes? Raster image?

Comment: @WELZ It's a compound path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on a regular path or outlined stroke.

1. Release the clipping mask
2. Select all
3. Get the **Shape Builder Tool**   [image: shape]
4. Pressing **Alt** to delete, click on each part of the path that exceeds the frame.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider creating a (whole) shape of the state (SC) which would be thesame size etc. (you're just adding to the open area) and use *that* to make the actual clipping mask (so that it's separate and you can leave the other path open)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the clipping mask transfers to the outlined stroke. Since this is a logo and will be used by various people, I think you are on the right track with the reasoning the stroke needs to be expanded. What I would do is:

- Release the mask
- Expand the stroke
- Use the pathfinder or shape builder to remove the parts that stick out.
- Clean up your design (e.g. merge the shapes that use the same colors, etc.)

Then you will be sure that everything will remain to scale when someone else implements your logo.